# ERROR Cutline feature without a geometry

Tags: qgis, clip, error

I am using QGIS 2.18.24. I'm trying to clip raster (asc) by mask (shp).
I'm working in EPSG:4326.

- I'm checking the geometry of the polygon file, no errors were found.
- Geometry is valid.
- Edit mode is disabled.

I'm always getting the following error message that I haven't been able to sort out:

```
Algorithm Clip raster by mask layer starting...
GDAL command:
gdalwarp -ot Float32 -q -of GTiff -cutline C:\Users\Urbana\Desktop\tesi\Europa_shp\EUROPA_OK.shp -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PREDICTOR=1 -co ZLEVEL=6 -wo OPTIMIZE_SIZE=TRUE "C:\\Users\\Urbana\\Desktop\\tesi\\variabili current\\Nuova cartella\\bio01.asc" C:\Users\Urbana\AppData\Local\Temp\processingf8e7cc09212f4e19a00d49110f0c0b1c\a879020e1c284cfaabb238991ac727b1\OUTPUT.tif
GDAL command output:
ERROR 1: Cutline feature without a geometry. 
Converting outputs
Caricamento layer

The following layers were not correctly generated.
Ritagliato (da maschera)
You can check the log messages to find more information about the execution of the algorithm
```

Comment: What does command `ogrinfo -al -so C:\Users\Urbana\Desktop\tesi\Europa_shp\EUROPA_OK.shp` show?

Comment: the destination of the cut

Comment: I don't understand. It should print the coordinate system of the shapefile, the count of features, and the attribute schema.

Comment: I have: shape file with europe (mask), which I have modified to have the areas of my interest and climatic variables. I don't understand my output.

Comment: Copy and paste into your question what ogrinfo reports.

Comment: sorry, but can you tell me how to do it?